# fix magento menue from displaying in the wrong area

Tags: css, magento, menu

I was editing the menu in magento and i changed the text from

[image: original menue]

and i changed it to

[image: changed meue]

now the navigation has moved below the black area i didn't not change any code i dont understad how this happen to have a look at the website it is http://truckpartsactions.com/  to take a look at the origianl website http://65enginespart.com/

Comment: if you have backup file, you can replace it.....

Comment: this class header-container has fixed height due to this this problem occur ed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the text, it is because of the new logo dimensions
The original logo is 151*100
Your logo is 200*121
If you resize the new logo or just add in styles.css:

```
.logo img { height:100px; } //or max-height:100px;
```

The menu will come back to the black area